# jcrop is not resizing box dimension properly on live

Tags: html, jcrop

I am using jcrop for cropping image in my project. I have set jcrop box in a bootstrap modal and set jcrop parameter boxHeight 400 and boxWidth 600. My jcrop code is:

```js
$("#cropbox").attr('src', "**Dynamic image path**");
$("#cropbox").show();
$("#cropbox").Jcrop({
  bgOpacity: .5,
  aspectRatio: 7/10,
  setSelect: [ 60, 70, 540, 330 ],
  onSelect: updateCoords1,
  boxWidth: 600,
  boxHeight: 400
});
```

This code is working fine in local host but not working properly on live. The problem is regarding resizing issue of crop box. The original image and screen shot of local and live are:
**Original image**
[image: Original image]

**Local host**

[image: Working fine in local host]

**Live**
[image: Creating problem in live]

I have uploaded every file required. Both local and live having same js and css.
Please help me to find me solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, After long research, I find that bootstrap css overriding jcrop css max-width attribute and creating problem. So, I overwrite it by putting

```css
img {max-width: none}
```

in html code after bootstrap css is included.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this helped me a lot!